# Gateway Time-out on for each - sleep

Tags: php, apache

I am wokring on a very simple cronjob in php. But when executing this code

```
for($i=0;$i<=500;$i++){
 echo $i.'<br>';
sleep(1);
```

I get this error:

Gateway Time-out

The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.

Comment: Have you tried replacing 500 by 20 to be sure it is working fine ? 20 seconds is already long for executing a script. What is the maximum number you can put here before to get time-out error ?

Comment: Did you try to run the script from command line?
What's the cron entry?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this by imposing no limit at the script head..

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
?>
```